# What is the coefficient of $x^3 y^4$ in the expansion of $ (2x-y+5)^8$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I was thinking of doing $\binom{8}{4}$ but not sure if right.

Comment: Close, even though you can get the answer by applying Binomial theorem twice. what you really should do is use [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) directly.

Comment: If you take the $x$s first, then $y$s, you have 3 $(2x)$s, 4 $(-y)$s and one $5$ in the product. Now take appropriate combinations.

Comment: So do you mean C(8,4) * C(4,3) ? correct?

Comment: Using the program, the result is 11200.

Comment: @user3015986 you are missing the $2^3 (-1)^4 5^{8-3-4}$ factor. Can you see where they come from?

Comment: Following my comment, you have $\binom{8}{3} \binom{5}{4} 2^3 (-1)^4 5$. There is nothing special about my order of operations either...

Comment: @achille hui can you explain to me where that comes from? Is it a special case if you have a constant? 

My book does it with just Combinations but it doesn't have an example for constants.

Comment: @user3015986 Let's look at a simpler example of extracting the coefficient of $xy$ from $(2x+3y)^2$. By binomial theorem,

$$(2x+3y)^2 = \binom{2}{0}(2x)^2 + \binom{2}{1}(2x)(3y) + \binom{2}{2}(3y)^2$$
The coefficient for $xy$ come from the middle term only. However, in additional to the binomial coefficient $\binom{2}{1}$, you have an extra factor $2 \cdot 3$ comes from expanding the $(2x)(3y)$ term. So the final result is $\binom{2}{1}(2)(3) = 12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the binomial expansion  $$(2x-y+5)^8=^{8}C_0(2x-y)^85^0+\color{red}{^{8}C_1(2x-y)^75^1}+^{8}C_2(2x-y)^65^2+^{8}C_3(2x-y)^55^3+^{8}C_4(2x-y)^45^4+\dots +^{8}C_8(2x-y)^05^8$$

In the given term $x^3y^4$, the sum of powers $3+4=7$ hence in the above expansion there is only one term $^{8}C_1(2x-y)^75^1$ which has sum of powers $7$ hence using binomial expansion of $^{8}C_1(2x-y)^75^1$ as follows $$^{8}C_1(2x-y)^75^1=\color{blue}{5(^{8}C_1)}[^{7}C_0(2x)^7(-y)^0+^{7}C_1(2x)^6(-y)^1+^{7}C_2(2x)^5(-y)^2+^{7}C_3(2x)^4(-y)^3+\color{red}{^{7}C_4(2x)^3(-y)^4}\ldots +^{7}C_7(2x)^0(-y)^7]$$
Hence, the coefficient of $x^3y^4$ of $5(^{8}C_1)(^{7}C_4)(2x)^3(-y)^4$ is given as $$=5(^{8}C_1)(^{7}C_4)(2)^3(-1)^4$$
$$=5(8)(35)(8)(1)=\color{red}{11200}$$

Answer (score 6):

Pre-expansion, there are $8$ factors of $2x - y + 5$.

From those $8$ factors, choose the $3$ that contribute to the $x^3$, from the remaining $5$ factors, choose the $4$ that will contribute to $y^4$.  There is only 1 factor left so it chooses itself.

Post-expansion, that's ${8 \choose 3}{5 \choose 4}{1 \choose 1}$ terms with $x^3y^4$, and taking into account the initial coefficients of $\{2, -1, 5\}$, the final coefficient is:

$${8 \choose 3}{5 \choose 4}2^3(-1)^45^1 = 11200$$

Comment: Very clean and lucid explanation. +1. Made it seem so easy and obvious

Answer (score 2):

One has $$(2x-y+5)^8 = \sum_{i=0}^8 {8 \choose i} (2x-y)^i 5^{8-i} = \sum_{i=0}^8 {8 \choose i} 5^{8-i}\sum_{j=0}^i {i\choose j} (2x)^jy^{i-j}(-1)^{i-j}.$$

Then, one gets the coefficient of $x^3y^4$ is $${8 \choose 7}5^{8-7}{7\choose 3}2^3.$$

Comment: Don't you miss a binomial coefficient in your inner binomial sum?

Comment: @mickep Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The $r,0\le r\le8$th term of $$(2x-y+5)^8=\{(2x+5)-y\}^8$$ is $$\binom8ry^{8-r}(2x+5)^{8-r}(-y)^r$$

So, we need $r=4$

So, we focus on $$\binom84y^{8-4}(2x+5)^{8-4}(-y)^4$$

Now the $n,0\le n\le4$th term of $$(2x+5)^4$$ is $$\binom4n(2x)^{4-n}5^n$$

We need $4-n=3$

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it using the [multinomial theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)